# How to use python requests to post image to gitlab

Tags: python, python-requests, gitlab, gitlab-api

I'm fairly new to using the python requests library, and am currently trying to download an image off of JIRA and then upload that image to gitlab to later reference in a note, as documented here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#upload-a-file. The image is downloading properly from JIRA (I can see and open the file), however, I am getting an error 400 Bad Request response right now when I try and post it to gitlab.

My code looks like this:

```
gl_url = 'https://lab.mygitlabinstance.com/api/v4/projects/%s/uploads' % gl_project_id

def image_post(image_url, file_name, jira_auth, gl_url, gl_token):
    image = requests.get(
        image_url,
        auth=HTTPBasicAuth(*jira_auth),
        stream=True)
    local_file = open(file_name, 'wb')
    image.raw.decode_content = True
    shutil.copyfileobj(image.raw, local_file)
    file = {'file': '@' + file_name}
    value = requests.post(
        gl_url,
        headers={'PRIVATE-TOKEN': gl_token, 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
        verify=True,
        files=file
    )
    return value
```

My gitlab token is working in other parts of the same program, so I don't think that that is the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How big is the image size? Do you get this error posting other images as well?

Comment: The image is 313 kB.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```py
def image_post(image_url, file_name, jira_auth, gl_url, gl_token):
    image = requests.get(
        image_url,
        auth=HTTPBasicAuth(*jira_auth),
        stream=True)
    
    # save file locally
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(image.content)
    
    # readfile and send
    file = {'file': open(file_name, 'rb')}
    value = requests.post(
        gl_url,
        headers={'PRIVATE-TOKEN': gl_token},
        verify=True,
        files=file
    )
    return value
```

---

Or probably Second one:

I'm not sure what is in your `local_file`, but `'@'+filename` is for `curl` syntax, here we need file content so try fix line in your example to this one: `file = {'file': local_file}`